# Google Sheets transform horizontal to vertical with gaps

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transformation, node-csv-transform

I need a conversion of the individual cells for a wordpress plugin. I have a huge amount of data that I need to transform ! I had already tried it with TRANSFORM=(A1:A4) , but I do not get the result.
And of course there must be a gap after the last text section. In this case ( src ). I hope someone can help me.

ps: I found a [Tutorial on YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHV_NaunmT0) , i gonna try it :)

[image: Google Sheets transform with space/gap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:D1 & "♥" & FILTER(A2:D, A2:A <> "")), "♥",,))
```

[image]

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:D1  <- you mean mybe A1:C1, i got only 3 rows.
It doesnt work :/
Message -> Error

Comment: I added `D` for the gap.

Comment: what do you mean with the hearts ? :D
i am reading more about FLATTEN. Thanks for putting me on the right track :) but am a little annoyed, does not work

Comment: @DawidFleszewski `♥` is just a separator which is rare in common texts. Works on my test sheet: [pic](https://i.imgur.com/qLQY1zX.png)

Comment: You are Pro. Im very happy, thank you very much. it did not work at first.

Very helpful for others who are looking for exactly the same thing. Change your language in Sheets ! I changed to english and it works. Thank you ;)